# Divergence of vector field multiplied by identity matrix yields what exactly?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Im trying to perform $\nabla \cdot u I$, where $u$ is a vector field. I expected the result to be:

$$ \pmatrix{ \frac{du_x}{dx}, 0, 0 \cr 0, \frac{du_y}{dy}, 0 \cr 0, 0, \frac{du_z}{dz} } $$

However my result was:

$$\pmatrix{ \frac{du_x}{dx}+\frac{du_y}{dy}+\frac{du_z}{dz}, 0, 0 \cr 0, \frac{du_x}{dx}+\frac{du_y}{dy}+\frac{du_z}{dz}, 0 \cr 0, 0, \frac{du_x}{dx}+\frac{du_y}{dy}+\frac{du_z}{dz} } $$

Because $\nabla \cdot u$ is a scalar... right? Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the results makes any sense if $u$ is indeed a vector field, as it then has $3$ components and you can't fit him into your matrix.

$u$ is obviously a scalar field, so you first calculate $uI$ and get 
$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{d}{dx} &\frac{d}{dy} &\frac{d}{dz}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}u & 0 & 0\\ 0 & u & 0\\ 0 & 0 & u\end{bmatrix}$$
which is exactly $$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{du}{dx} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & \frac{du}{dy} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \frac{du}{dz}\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: You are probably right, but I dont really get it yet. My $u$ represents displacement in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It has 3 values. Probably my expectancy was wrong. If it were an vector field, would my result be correct?

Comment: If it were a vector field, you must write which component goes where. You have $u=\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_3\end{bmatrix}$ and you first multiply it by $\Delta$ so you get $\frac{du_1}{dx} + \frac{du_2}{dy} + \frac{du_3}{dz}$ and then multiply it by $I$ so you get almost what you got.

Note, however, that the order of operations changed. It's always good to be careful with these things.

Answer (score 0):

Let be $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.The above is a mistake, because if $u$ is a scalar field we have the following:

\begin{equation*}
div_x (\textbf{uI})=\nabla\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
u & 0 & 0\\
0 & u & 0 \\
0 & 0 & u 
\end{pmatrix}
=(\partial_{x_1}, \partial_{x_2}, \partial_{x_3})\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
u & 0 & 0\\
0 & u & 0 \\
0 & 0 & u 
\end{pmatrix}=(\partial_{x_1} u, \partial_{x_2} u, \partial_{x_3} u)=\nabla_{x} u
\end{equation*}

Remember that you have a $1\times 3$ matrix with $3\times 3$ matrix and the results is a $1\times 3$ matrix.

If $u$ is a vector field, i.e $u=(u_1,u_2, u_3)^T$ we have the following:

\begin{equation*}
\text{div}_x (\textbf{Iu})=\nabla\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
u_3  
\end{pmatrix}
=(\partial_{x_1}, \partial_{x_2}, \partial_{x_3})\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
u_3  
\end{pmatrix}=\partial_{1} u_1+\partial_{2} u_2+\partial_{3} u_3=\text{div}_x u
\end{equation*}
Remember that you have a $1\times 3$ matrix with $3\times 1$ matrix and the results is a real.